# Firestore returning less documents

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So in my android app I'm fetching all the documents from a collection by the following code :

```
    log("Player Listener Started")
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("players")
        .limit(4)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
            log("Player Listener firestore exception message ${firebaseFirestoreException?.localizedMessage}")
            if (firebaseFirestoreException == null) {

                querySnapshot?.documents!!.forEach {
                    val serverPlayer = it.toObject(Player::class.java)!!
                    snapshotPlayers.add(serverPlayer)
                }
                log("Player numbers : ${snapshotPlayers.size}")
```

I've 4 documents in "players" collection in the database :

[image]

But it always return just 1 document i.e. "Sheetal". Please check the log from the above code :

[image]

This exact code was working fine an hour ago and I was getting all 4 users. 
I cleared database from the console and re-created these document using my app this code is not returning 4 documents.

`Player` class :

```
class Player(
var name: String = "",
var gameId: String = "",
var currentCard: Card = Card(),
var cardList: ArrayList<Card> = ArrayList(),
var made: String = "0",
var expected: String = "0",
var message: String = "",
var order: Int = 0,
var turn: Int? = null
)
```

`Player` document contents in the database

[image]

I tried these things but still getting same result :

1. Clear my app cache manually
2. Cleared Firestore persistence data using `FireDB.db.clearPersistence()`

Its my first project in firestore so I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please help me.

UPDATED LOGCAT:
[image]

Comment: What is that `serverPlayer`?

Comment: Sorry a line was missing in between . Updated the code now.

Comment: Have you tried to log the `firebaseFirestoreException`?

Comment: Not yet but isn't that null ? I've checked that as you can see in the code .

Comment: Check to see if it's not `null`. That's the point. Is it something printed out?

Comment: I checked `firebaseFirestoreException` is always null. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Also I checked in log there is nothing printed out . I've attached one more screenshot of the logcat with updated code

Comment: Please add the content of your `Player` class and another screenshot with the content of those documents.

Comment: @AlexMamo updated with `Player` class and a screenshot of document contents from database.